# Issues with displaying data from SQLite database into spinner [Android]

Tags: android, database, spinner, sqlite

I need help in how to retrieve data from SQLite database and put into spinner.
Plus, I can't open my android app and the LogCat says "No such column:name". I have even check with my DBAdapter classes and non-DBAdapter classes.

I have two DBAdapter classes(InfoDBAdapter.java and BuddiesDBAdapter.java) both link to my PersonalInfo.java class.

Below are the codes for retrieving data from database and put into spinner(PersonalInfo.class).

```
InfoDBAdapter infoDB = new InfoDBAdapter(this);

//BuddiesDBAdapter buddyDB = new BuddiesDBAdapter(this);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.info);

BuddiesDBAdapter buddyDB = new BuddiesDBAdapter(this);

buddyDB.open();
Cursor c = buddyDB.getAllContacts();

//Create an array to specify which fields want to display
    String[] from = new String[] {"name"};

    //Create an array of the display item want to bind our data to
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.fName};

    nameSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.nameSpinner);

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, c, from, to);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    nameSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    buddyDB.close();
```

and these are the insert codes for inserting informaton into database.

```
btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    infoDB.open();
                    long id;

                    Spinner nameSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.nameSpinner);
                    String NameValue = nameSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    EditText txtDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
                    String DateValue = txtDate.getText().toString();

                    EditText txtType = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtType);
                    String TypeValue = txtType.getText().toString();

                    EditText txtLikes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLikes);
                    String LikesValue = txtLikes.getText().toString();

                    EditText txtDislikes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDislikes);
                    String DislikesValue = txtDislikes.getText().toString();

                    id = infoDB.insertContact(NameValue, DateValue, TypeValue, LikesValue, DislikesValue);
                    infoDB.close();

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                            "Your information is saved successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
```

Below are the two DBAdapter classes

InfoDBAdapter.java

```
public class InfoDBAdapter
{
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    public static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";
    public static final String KEY_LIKES = "likes";
    public static final String KEY_DISLIKES = "dislikes";

    private static final String TAG = "InfoDBAdapter";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "anniversary";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "friends";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table friends(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "name text not null, date text not null, type text not null, likes text not null, dislikes text not null);";

    private final Context context;

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public InfoDBAdapter(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            try
            {
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            } catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }// end onCreate()

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS friends");
            onCreate(db);
        }// end onUpgrade()

    }// end DatabaseHelper

        public InfoDBAdapter open() throws SQLException
        {
            db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }// end open()

        public void close()
        {
            DBHelper.close();
        }// end close()

        public long insertContact(String name, String date, String type, String likes, String dislikes)
        {
            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
            initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);
            initialValues.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
            initialValues.put(KEY_LIKES, likes);
            initialValues.put(KEY_DISLIKES, dislikes);
            return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
        }// end insertContact()

        public boolean deleteContact(long rowId)
        {
            return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
        }// end deleteContact()

        public Cursor getAllContacts()
        {
            return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] 
                    { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_DATE, KEY_TYPE, KEY_LIKES, KEY_DISLIKES }, null, null, null, null, null);
        }// end getAllContacts()

        public Cursor getContact(long rowId) throws SQLException
        {
            Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                    KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_DATE, KEY_TYPE, KEY_LIKES, KEY_DISLIKES }, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId,
                    null, null, null, null, null);
            if (mCursor != null)
            {
                mCursor.moveToFirst();
            }
            return mCursor;
        }// end getContact()

        public boolean updateContact(long rowId, String name, String date, String type, String likes, String dislikes)
        {
            ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
            args.put(KEY_NAME, name);
            args.put(KEY_DATE, date);
            args.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
            args.put(KEY_LIKES, likes);
            args.put(KEY_DISLIKES, dislikes);
            return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
        }// end updateContact()
}//end DBAdapter
```

BuddiesDBAdapter.java

```
public class BuddiesDBAdapter
{
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "buddy_name";
    private static final String TAG = "BuddiesDBAdapter";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "anniversary";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "buddiesList";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table namesList(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "buddy_name text not null);";

    private final Context context;

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public BuddiesDBAdapter(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            try
            {
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            } catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }// end onCreate()

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS namesList");
            onCreate(db);
        }// end onUpgrade()

    }//end DatabaseHelper class

    public BuddiesDBAdapter open() throws SQLException
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }// end open()

    public void close()
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }// end close()

    public long insertContact(String buddy_name)
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, buddy_name);
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, values);         
    }//end insertContact()


    public boolean deleteContact(long rowId)
    {
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }// end deleteContact()


    public Cursor getAllContacts()
    {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] 
                { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME }, null, null, null, null, null);
    }// end getAllContacts()

    public Cursor getContact(long rowId) throws SQLException
    {
        Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME }, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId,
                null, null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null)
        {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }// end getContact()

    public boolean updateContact(long rowId, String buddy_name)
    {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_NAME, buddy_name);
        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }//end updateContact()
}
```

I need help with this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks alot!

Comment: You are using `date text not null` while creating a table, the column name `date` is causes the problem, try rename it with `_date`

Comment: I still have the same problem when I re-named to _date.

Comment: LogCat still says: 08-06 12:00:12.349: E/AndroidRuntime(536): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'name' does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above answer is correct. What is confusing is that you have two different db adapters and the table name/column names are different.

For maintainability, I would not hard code the column names, but instead use

```
String[] from = new String[] {BuddiesDBAdapter.KEY_NAME};
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I've tried it but i get force close message. Then i renamed KEY_NAME with buddy_name, but still no data displayed in the spinner. I'm not sure if i made any mistakes in the codes or miss out any codes.

Comment: Make sure that you have a consistent set of rows commented in and out. Use the same class which you "open" for your data. Outside of that, I see no issue. Also, if your column name is "buddy_name", your error should not show "name"

Comment: What do you mean by "conistent set of rows commented in and out"? Do you mean I need to have same rows in both DBAdapters?

Comment: What I meant by consistent is between infoDB and buddyDB. Use only one of them consistently for all your code. For example, your code above was confusing as to which adapter you were using and which column name you had added. That was all. Thanks for accepting.

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
   String[] from = new String[] {"name"};
```

should be

```
   String[] from = new String[] {"buddy_name"};
```

Comment: must I put TextView id or the Spinner id in String[] to = new String[]{} ? Because I can't see any data(from the database) displayed in the spinner. But i can open the app.