# can I create a database on a button click in Android to send my spinner data to

Tags: android, android-intent

So I have set up part of my app where a user will select up to five things from from spinners (five spinners in total) and right now I have the button sending the selections to a new activity via an intent and they display on a new activity but I want to store the selections to an internal database on the button click and then the user can retrieve their selections from the menu buy pushing the button  show data.

```
 public class IwiSelect extends Activity {

Spinner spinner1, spinner2, spinner3, spinner4, spinner5;
Button btnSubmit; 
String text;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_iwiselect);

    addListenerOnButton();
}
// get the selected drop down list value
  public void addListenerOnButton() {
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    spinner4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
    spinner5 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner5);

    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            String text0 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String text1 = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String text2 = spinner3.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String text3 = spinner4.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String text4 = spinner5.getSelectedItem().toString();

            //Starting a new Intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(IwiSelect.this, SecondScreenActivity.class);

            //Sending data to another Activity
            intent.putExtra("IWI0", text0);
            intent.putExtra("IWI1", text1);
            intent.putExtra("IWI2", text2);
            intent.putExtra("IWI3", text3);
            intent.putExtra("IWI4", text4);


        // starting new activity
            startActivity(intent);

}
    });

  }
  }
```

this class sends the data to the new screen.

the class below is my helper class

```
 public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "iwi";

    //  table name
    private static final String TABLE_IWI = "iwis";


    //  Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "iwiname";


    public DatabaseHandler(SecondScreenActivity secondScreenActivity) {
        super((Context) secondScreenActivity, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

     // Creating Tables
        @Override
       public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_IWI_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_IWI + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_IWI_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_IWI);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }




    // Deleting single contact
    public void deleteIwi(Iwi iwi) {}


    // Adding new contact
    public void addIwi(Iwi iwi) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, iwi.getName());


    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_IWI, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // Getting single contact
    public Iwi getIwi(int id) {
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

     Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_IWI, new String[] { KEY_ID,
         KEY_NAME, }, KEY_ID + "=?",
         new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
     if (cursor != null)
     cursor.moveToFirst();

     Iwi iwi = new Iwi(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
          cursor.getString(1));
     // return contact
     return iwi;
     }


     // Getting All Contacts
       public List<Iwi> getAllIwi() {
     List<Iwi> iwiList = new ArrayList<Iwi>();
     // Select All Query
     String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_IWI;

     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
     Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

     // looping through all rows and adding to list
     if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      do {
         Iwi iwi = new Iwi();
         iwi.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
         iwi.setName(cursor.getString(1));

         // Adding contact to list
         iwiList.add(iwi);
     } while (cursor.moveToNext());
     }

     // return contact list
     return iwiList;
    }

    //Getting contacts Count
    public int getIwiCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_IWI;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
    }

     // Updating single contact
    public int updateIwi(Iwi iwi) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, iwi.getName());


    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_IWI, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
           new String[] { String.valueOf(iwi.getID()) });
   }

    // Deleting single contact
    public void deleteContact(Iwi iwi) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_IWI, KEY_ID + " = ?",
           new String[] { String.valueOf(iwi.getID()) });
    db.close();
    }

    }
```

Comment: Yes its possible ..When you clicking the button you have have a database..For that you should have separate `database helper` class .in that You should have query for `"storing"` and then you can implement your logic there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store these values ; Instead of database , SharedPreferences can be used-

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
              "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // To Edit the shared preferences-
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

     editor.putString("IWI0", text0);
     editor.putString("IWI1", text1);
     editor.putString("IWI2", text2);
     editor.putString("IWI3", text3);
     editor.putString("IWI4", text4);
     editor.commit();

     // To retrieve the data--
     SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
     String restoredText = prefs.getString("IWI0", null);
     if (restoredText != null) 
     {
       // Do something
     }
```

**Edit** :
Reference-
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: As per the documentation-  This data will persist across user sessions (even if your application is killed).

Comment: it throws an error The method getSharedPreferences(String, int) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){} what should I put in this method

Comment: Edited my answer. The reason the error was there because "this" refers to the current context which was View.OnClickListener(){} . getSharedPreferences() is defined for application context.

Answer (score 1):

what is your exact problem? ya it is possible to create a database on button click.

Comment: I am not sure how to go about it do I code the database inside the onClickListener?

Comment: you can refer this links http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822323/issues-with-displaying-data-from-sqlite-database-into-spinner-android

Comment: http://www.android10.org/index.php/articlesdatastorage/235-creating-and-using-databases-in-android-one   http://www.androidhive.info/2012/06/android-populating-spinner-data-from-sqlite-database/                                             see that one also